# Return Data via Meteor Method within a Loop

Tags: meteor

I'm looping through a list of credit card transactions and need to call out to the credit card processor to get the current status. I tried to use a helper that calls a method, but it doesn't get rendered on the template. If I log to the console, I can see that the results are properly being returned, though.

```html
<tbody>
    {{#each donations}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ transactionId }} {{ status transactionId }}</td>
            <td>{{ donorName donor }}</td>
            <td>{{ donorEmail donor }}</td>
            <td>{{ formatMoney amount }}</td>
            <td>{{ createdAt }}</td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

Pulling the data:

```js
donations: function() {
    return Donations.find({
        type: 'Credit Card',
        createdAt: { $gte: new Date('Jan 1, 2015'), $lt: new Date('Jun 30, 2015') }
    });
},
```

The `status` helper:

```js
status: function(transactionId) {
    var transaction = Meteor.call('getTransactionInfo', transactionId, function(error, result) {
        console.log(result);
        return result.status;
    });
}
```

And the method:

```js
getTransactionInfo: function(transactionId) {
    var transaction = Meteor.wrapAsync(gateway.transaction.find, gateway.transaction);
    var response = transaction(transactionId);
    return response;
},
```

I found several questions that talked about [putting the data in a `ReactiveVar`](http://meteorpad.com/pad/SgZcFbpXXSRDLqRD2/MethodTest) or `Session` variable, but I don't know how I could use that, considering that I am returning the info for every instance of the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new template `donation`. Each row in the table will be its own `donation` instance, like this:

```html
<tbody>
    {{#each donations}}
        {{> donation }}
    {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

Now inside the `onCreated` for the `donation` template, create a `ReactiveVar`. Then immediately call the method, and in the method's callback, set the `ReactiveVar`. Since each row is its own template instance, each row will end up with its own `ReactiveVar`.

```js
Template.donation.onCreated(function () {
    var status = new ReactiveVar(null);
    this.status = status;
    Meteor.call('getTransactionInfo', this.data.transactionId, function (err, result) {
        if (err) { /* handle it */ }
        status.set(result);
    });
});

Template.donation.helpers({
    status: function () { return Template.instance().status.get(); },
    /* rest of the helpers */
});
```

Now when the template is first created, the method call is still ongoing, so `status.get()` returns `null`. We have to test for this and display a loading spinner. After the method call completes, `status.get()` will be set to the result, so the spinner will be replaced with the value.

```html
<tr>
    <td>
        {{ transactionId }}
        {{#if status}}
            {{ status }}
        {{else}}
            loading... <!-- or display a spinner -->
        {{/if}}
    </td>
    <td>{{ donorName donor }}</td>
    <td>{{ donorEmail donor }}</td>
    <td>{{ formatMoney amount }}</td>
    <td>{{ createdAt }}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

From a security pov you've just exposed a lookup to your bank's systems from your (untrusted) clients. Anyone can run `Meteor.call('getTransactionInfo', this.data.transactionId...)` from their browser and that will end up hitting your bank. Great DDOS vector. Even absent malicious users these computations will end up running repeatedly for every transaction.

Better approach: run a cron job on your server that periodically checks the status of transactions (until they have cleared and no longer need checking) and put those stati into your donation collection.

Comment: "getTransactionInfo" has security checks. This is an "admin" section only for backend management.

Comment: Even if the code is only run by admin users the call itself can easily be found. Also see my comment about this running repeatedly. Don't be surprised if your bank shuts down your api access at some point.